# Can't get Apache directory indexing to stop

Tags: apache2, apache-config

I am trying to get my OSX MacPorts install of Apache to NOT show directory listings.  I have tried various configurations of the "options" directive in the httpd.conf file with no luck.  When I go to the site, it still lists the root directory (there is no index file at the moment.)

Apache has been restarted after each change.

There is no .htaccess file in the / directory, so there shouldn't be anything overriding.

This is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically something is overriding your config. From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) of apache we can read that `Options` is can be placed in various context: server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess. 
`httpd.conf` is read first, so if You provided the configuration properly there, it means that it is overridden somewhere else

How did You do enter the options in the config ? In the most basic variant it should be.

```
<Directory /path>
     Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Here what you should do:

- check module configurations in `modules` for `Options Indexes`
- check the main virtualhost definition, probably called `default` or `000-default`

If it still does not help, add `Options -Indexes` to your virtualhost directly (provided you have not done it already). Or add it to the `.htaccess` file in your directory (allowing Options in .htaccess needs to be switched on)[as suggested in comments]

Comment: You could also try just adding "Options -Indexes" to a root .htaccess file... since I have no idea what your configuration is, I can't say whether that will work.

Comment: @alanaktion that is why I tried to cover everything in the answer :)

Comment: Turns out it was in every line of the vhosts file.  I've generally been using Webmin for configuration, but for some reason the indexing element wasn't registering anywhere in Webmin.  Anyway, removing the lines from the vhosts file solved the problem.